# How can I find which object in Java class can't be serialized?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm getting the following error in my application:

```
WARNING: Cannot serialize session attribute org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateHolder for session 27420D80AE859865FCD27E869C330659
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.his.op.patreg.web.RegistrationForm$5
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1129)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor165.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1129)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor165.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:440)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateHolder.writeObject(AjaxStateHolder.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.FileStore.save(FileStore.java:341)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.PersistentValve.invoke(PersistentValve.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The stack trace isn't providing any good information on which object is not able to serialize. Is there a good way to find the problem child?
My Class is too big and contains a lot of properties and that property contains several other properties so its very difficult to find out which property is not serializable.

Comment: It looks like `com.his.op.patreg.web.RegistrationForm$5`

Comment: Off course the issue is in the RegistrationForm class only and that class implements serializable . But there are number of properties inside that class and I don't know which property in that class is causing the NotSerializableException. Is there any way to find out which property in that class is the reason for this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true` to the JVM.

Eg: Add `SET CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true` in the startup.bat

Answer (score 2):

This part of the stack trace:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.his.op.patreg.web.RegistrationForm$5
```

is the non-serializable class. `RegistrationForm$5` means it's an anonymous class instantiated in `com.his.op.patreg.web.RegistrationForm`.

Answer (score 1):

Look for `com.his.op.patreg.web.RegistrationForm$5` (which is named `RegistrationForm$5.class` in your target directory) and open it in an IDE which will decompile it.

The contents should give you a hint on which anonymous class inside `RegistrationForm` it is. Then make that class implement `Serializable`.